# Vue import HTML from local file

Tags: html, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am looking for a way to import HTML content from a file which is in

```html
/src/activities/0/2/content.html
```

The two numbers are variables.

I need to do something like

```js
mounted(){
   this.foo = require('/src/activities/0/2/content.html')
}
```

```html
<div>
{{ foo }}
</div>
```

But I do not find a way to do this. If someone knows a solution, it will be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Vue's webpack needs to understand how to load `.html` files.  You can use [`html-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader).  Install it first:

```
npm install html-loader --save-dev
```

Then edit (or create) `vue.config.js` in the project root (not `src`).  From [the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#adding-a-new-loader):

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('html')
      .test(/\.html$/)
      .use('html-loader')
      .loader('html-loader')
  }
};
```

Now you can import HTML files like:

```js
import html from '@/activities/0/2/content.html'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      html,   // es6 property shorthand syntax
      foo: null
    }
  }
}
```

and use `html` like any other data variable.  Or you can do it the way you asked with `require`:

```js
mounted(){
   this.foo = require('@/activities/0/2/content.html')
}
```

`@` is an alias for `src`