# How to retrieve data from HTM file and convert to json using <input file> in Javascript (Vue)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, input

I'm trying to upload a HTM file using  in Vue. The data is actually a styled table using , , etc...

My question is that, is it possible to filter out the tabulated data in HTM into other forms of data, say JSON? - Picture below (taken from browser elements of the htm) - Basically I just want to filter out html syntaxes and just retrieve the data.

[image]

Comment: sure, you could process the rows, each row could have the values of the cells in an array ... so you'd end up with a 2d array like `[[row1-cell1, row1-cell2,.....],[r2c1, r2c2,....], ...]`

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+parse+html+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169217/vue-import-html-from-local-file

Comment: thing is, this is vue ... how was the table created in the first place?

Comment: @Chiu After upload HTML file, You mean you are getting HTML content as a response from an API call and you want to just filtered out the html syntaxes ? If yes, you can achieve that by using `RegEx` and remove the HTML syntaxes.

Comment: @JaromandaX it is a HTM file being uploaded to a website created using Vue.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal no, basically it's a HTML file generated from a machine (which in turn is a table of tabulated data - as shown in the pic), the file will be uploaded to a cloud database but before that I am going to process the data in json (only thing is the file is in html, but if you can filter out the html syntaxes with `RegEx` - should be ok) Thanks though

Comment: You should be able to use a DOM parser. There is one built into your browser: `new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlFileAsString, 'text/html')`. If you're on a Node.JS server you can use an npm package like [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use `RegEx` to filter HTML syntaxes.

Similar post:
[Regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).