# How can I use the correct html-loader to import a html file into my existing Vue 3 project?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to import an HTML file into my Vue project. I've already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169217/vue-import-html-from-local-file) and answer, but it doesn't seem to work for me, although I follow the steps it suggests. Here's what I tried:

**My HTML File:**

I've created a brand new Vue project using `vue create vue-html`. Before I could use `npm run serve`, I had to [install Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70482953/7385440) using the command `npm i vue@3.2.26`. Then I installed the `html-loader` using the command: `npm install html-loader --save-dev`. From here I've added an HTML file (`NetworkDiagram.html`) inside the `components` folder inside `src`. In here I've defined only the most basic HTML to see if it works: `<h1>Hello world!</h1>`.

**My App.vue:**

I've added 3 lines of code to import the NetworkDiagram component into the existing `App.vue` file (which works).

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
  <NetworkDiagram />      // I've added this line (1/3)
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import NetworkDiagram from './components/NetworkDiagram.html' // This line (2/3)

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    NetworkDiagram // and this line (3/3)
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

**vue.config.js:**

Finally, I've changed the `vue.config.js` file from:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

**to:**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('html')
      .test('/\.html$/')
      .use('html-loader')
      .loader('html-loader')
  }
})
```

Once I run `npm run serve` the server starts up. Without the added code in `App.vue` it shows the standard Vue homepage for a new project, which is as expected. However, once I add the code it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/NetworkDiagram.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

To me this seems as if I'm not using (the correct) html-loader because whatever html tag I write, it gives me the same error, or I'm setting up my `vue.config.js` file incorrectly. So my question is: how can I use a working html loader to import an html file into my existing Vue application, preferably inside `App.vue`?

*Why am I trying to do this?*

For anyone interested: I'm trying to create an application that can work with [Cisco's Next UI toolkit](https://github.com/NeXt-UI/next-tutorials) to create a network diagram, however this library needs an html file to connect the code to. I've tried to add the code to a `.vue` file, but importing the needed js files into this file gives me tons of errors and doesn't seem to work.